# Drupal dynamic internal redirect

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, drupal-7, hook-menu

What I want is pretty simple. I have registered a path

```
function spotlight_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['congres'] = array(
        'title' => 'Congres',
        'title arguments' => array(2),
        'page callback' => 'taxonomy_term_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

When this menu item is triggered, I want to redirect (without changing the url) to a taxonomy page, of which the term is chosen in a function that runs when this function is called.

How can I do this (especcially without changing the url) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `taxonomy_term_page` directly as your `page callback` as you'd need to provide a load function to load the term, which is just going to be too difficult with the setup you've got.

Instead, define your own page callback as an intermediary and just return the output from  `taxonomy_term_page` directly:

```
function spotlight_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['congres'] = array(
    'title' => 'Congres',
    'page callback' => 'spotlight_taxonomy_term_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function spotlight_taxonomy_term_page() {
  // Get your term ID in whatever way you need
  $term_id = my_function_to_get_term_id();

  // Load the term
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($term_id);

  // Make sure taxonomy_term_page() is available
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.pages');

  // Return the page output normally provided at taxonomy/term/ID
  return taxonomy_term_page($term);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was using the custom callback, but changed it to the taxonomy page to test some stuff out. Anyhow, this worked like a charm. Thx very much !